# django Category -id value

Tags: python, django

I want the value to be the category which I pressed.

```
<div class = 'category_Choose'>
<input type='text' name = 'category_id' value="???">
</div>
```

Example: if I choose category Anime I want this field value to be Anime.

```
class Category(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category_post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/', default = 'static/images/single_image.png')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How can I do this?

Comment: instead of input tag why don't you use select html tag?

Comment: that doesnot matter right now i just want to value to be the category which i choose , it will be select or input  doesnot matter to be honest

Comment: You need to show your view. Are you using a form class?

Comment: I dont  have yet done anything , i just dont know how to do it thats why asking  , i just created category  and put some values in category from admin page   now i want when i click category  page showed me exactly that category which i choose

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".posts").click(function(){
  var cat_name = $(this).data('category');
  $('input[name="category_id"]').val(cat_name)
  alert($('input[name="category_id"]').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="category_id" value="">

<a class="posts" data-category="cat_1">Post 1</a>
<a class="posts" data-category="cat_2">Post 2</a>
<a class="posts" data-category="cat_3">Post 3</a>
<a class="posts" data-category="cat_4">Post 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Jquery for this problem. You can render all your categories in the templates and then use jquery's hide and show methods.

Assuming your html looks like this,

```
<div id='categories'>

    <div id= 'category_id_1'>
        <p>category name 1</p>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>

    <div id= 'category_id_2'>
        <p>category name 2</p>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>

    .
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Your Jquery code to hide and show can look something like this,

```
document.ready(function(){

    var input = $('input');

    input.click(function(){

        /* Get the selected category_id */

        category_id = option.attr('name');

        $('#categories').find('.category').each(function(i){

            /* Show the category with the selected category id*/

            if ( $(this).attr('category_id') === category_id ){
                $(this).show()
            }
            else{
                $(this).hide()
            }
        });
    });
});
```